# ubuntu-server 2 network devices, 2 isp

Tags: ubuntu, routing, nic, isp, routes

Hello I have the following szenario:

I have 2 ISPs behind seperate routers, and one web/ssh-server with 2 ethernet cards.

I want the webserver to be reachable from both isp. I have forwarderd each router's port 80 to the local ip, but it seems that the server is only able to listen to 1 ip from outside. port-forwarding is fine, it must be a server issue (i changed ip to another webserver that worked)

If i access http://192.168.4.101 or http://192.168.2.101 from one of the networks it works just fine, but from outside one of the 2 nics seems to be unreachable.

More details:

```
#/etc/network/interfaces:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet static 
        address 192.168.4.101 
        netmask 255.255.255.0 
        network 192.168.4.0 
        broadcast 192.168.4.255 
        gateway 192.168.4.1 

auto eth1 
iface eth1 inet static 
        address 192.168.2.101 
        netmask 255.255.255.0 
        network 192.168.2.0 
        broadcast 192.168.2.255 
        gateway 192.168.2.1
```

Any ideas?
I think i have to adjust some internal routes on t

Comment: What web server, and how is it configured?

Comment: apache2, but it has to be a routing issue because i experienced the same problems with ssh as well... (port 22 is forwarded)

Comment: Stop using NAT and it all becomes a lot freakin' easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to setup your routing such that you respond on the interface through which the client established a connection; ie: as is maybe it's going through your default route , which doesn't make it back to the client.

please include your apache config, routing and iptables.